# Highstock align 0 values

Tags: highcharts

How can I align the 0 point on both Y axis?

-> I.e. display the 0 point on the same hight in the chart example

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L64q9fsp/

[image]

```
"yAxis": [{
    "labels": {},
    "opposite": false
  }, {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "tickPosition": "outside",
    "labels": {
      "align": "right",
      "x": 30,
      "style": {
        "color": "#ff0000"
      }
    }
  }],
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such default functionality, but you can try to use experimental Highcharts plugin from this user-voice disscusion: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2554384-multiple-axis-alignment-control

```
/**
 * Experimental Highcharts plugin to implement chart.alignThreshold option. This primary axis
 * will be computed first, then all following axes will be aligned to the threshold.
 * Author: Torstein Hønsi
 * Last revision: 2016-11-02
 */
(function(H) {
    var Axis = H.Axis,
        inArray = H.inArray,
        wrap = H.wrap;

    wrap(Axis.prototype, 'adjustTickAmount', function(proceed) {
        var chart = this.chart,
            primaryAxis = chart[this.coll][0],
            primaryThreshold,
            primaryIndex,
            index,
            newTickPos,
            threshold;

        // Find the index and return boolean result
        function isAligned(axis) {
            index = inArray(threshold, axis.tickPositions); // used in while-loop
            return axis.tickPositions.length === axis.tickAmount && index === primaryIndex;
        }

        if (chart.options.chart.alignThresholds && this !== primaryAxis) {
            primaryThreshold = (primaryAxis.series[0] && primaryAxis.series[0].options.threshold) || 0;
            threshold = (this.series[0] && this.series[0].options.threshold) || 0;

            primaryIndex = primaryAxis.tickPositions && inArray(primaryThreshold, primaryAxis.tickPositions);

            if (this.tickPositions && this.tickPositions.length &&
                primaryIndex > 0 &&
                primaryIndex < primaryAxis.tickPositions.length - 1 &&
                this.tickAmount) {

                // Add tick positions to the top or bottom in order to align the threshold
                // to the primary axis threshold
                while (!isAligned(this)) {

                    if (index < primaryIndex) {
                        newTickPos = this.tickPositions[0] - this.tickInterval;
                        this.tickPositions.unshift(newTickPos);
                        this.min = newTickPos;
                    } else {
                        newTickPos = this.tickPositions[this.tickPositions.length - 1] + this.tickInterval;
                        this.tickPositions.push(newTickPos);
                        this.max = newTickPos;
                    }
                    proceed.call(this);
                }
            }

        } else {
            proceed.call(this);
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/06f2bt78/